# how to formulate this combinatorics problem?

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms

Given first X natural numbers(1,2,3,4,....x) and calculate the sum of the maximum value of each subsequence of size n these numbers.

example x=2 and n=2
sequence -> 1,2

subsequnces-{1,2},{2,1},{1,1},{2,2}
sum=max{1,2}+max(2,1)+max(1,1)+max(2,2)
therefore sum =7

Idea:I have a idea but cant formulate it completely

Take the largest value of the sequence X and then take n-1 values from X-1
so that becomes 1*C(x-1,n-1)*n!

Now take 2 X so that leaves us with n-2 choices from x-1 elements and therfore  C(x-1,n-1)*n!/2! and so on in all these cases value would be 6 so multiply the entire thing with 6

Now think for max value x-1 and do the above process

Basically thinking how many times each max value can occur.

I was looking for a way to exactly think of this question and how to formulate into a formula.If thier are some other method or idea other than what i said i would highly want to know it.

Comment: consider decimal numbers from 111 to 999. Each number has a "roof"
i.e. a maximal figure, for example 321 -> 3, 788 -> 8. Calculate the sum of roofs   of the given numbers.

Comment: What was the intution behind using this idea

Comment: Your example does not seem to fit your problem statement as I understand it. $2,2$ is not a subsequence of $1,2$.

Comment: sorry its all combinations with position mattering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of sequences of length $n$ for which 1 is maximum is equal to 1 (11...1 $n$ times). The number of sequences of length $n$ for which 2 is maximum is equal to $2^n-1$ (consider sequences in which each element is 1 or 2, and ensure that there's at least one 2). 
More generally, $i$ is maximum in $i^n-(i-1)^n$ sequences (i.e. those sequences consisting of numbers from 1 to $i$, and having at least one $i$).

Thus, the sum is $\sum_{i=1}^{n} i\left(i^n-(i-1)^n \right)$, which can be simplified further.

Comment: I think we also have to consider subsequences $S$ with maximum element $j\in S$ where $S$ is a *proper subset* of $\{1,2,\ldots,j\}$. Neverthless (1+) for this nice starter.

Comment: Thanks for the correction.